# Dimmer Circuits 230v

Tags: electrical

My question relates to a commercial building, but the theory I guess is common to all.

Can I safely use a 230v dimmer circuit to feed a general lighting rig? I need to drop a 32A Ceeform cable to a portable show stand and have been advised not to. I believe the person who has made the statement, but want why it would be a problem?  My logic says that a dimmer set at 230v should have no problem in supplying a 500w (2Amp) lighting circuit!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do.  You're trying to tap an existing 230V lighting circuit (which has a dimmer on it) to power your 500W light?

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a dimmer on a socket, unless it is a special socket type only used for lighting.  If there is a possibility of someone plugging a motor into it, nope.

The Ceeform family of sockets have quite a variety of keying, and they are specifically used for theater lighting... so it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

I always hesitate when it comes to dimmer questions. It not like the "good old days" where you have a simple rheostat that connects to incandescent lamps. Then you only had to know the load in Watts. Nowadays there are electronic dimmers or combination types or even some with certain processors in them that recognise a certain load and adjusts to it. So you need to know the load, type of lamp, correct voltage, both the specifics of the driver or ballast and the dimmer.

I see no problem with your question or you logic. The real question would be is it approved for a certain application by the manufacturer?